# Snippet console logging JavaScript exception as empty object when using .log

Tags: bug, stack-snippets

When a JavaScript exception is caught in a snippet and the exception is output using console.log, it appears as an empty object.

Example:

```js
try {
  let foo = null;
  foo.bar;
} catch(exception) {
  console.log(exception);
  console.log("As opposed to:")
  console.error(exception);
}
```

Comment: What should be the correct behavior to you? Error Objects have no enumerable properties, so JSON.stringify(ErrorInstance) will return `"{}"`. Most browsers console seem to call a special toString method (including the call-stack as a second line) that is not specified anywhere (the available toString returning only ErrorInstance#ConstructorName: ErrorInstance#Message). Maybe that would be enough? (Would still require an `if(object instanceof Error)` which will likely slow down even more the stringification algo, for all logs...)

Comment: And actually the behavior I described above is only when logging the Error alone. When logged as part of an object structure they expose yet an other representation (more object like)

Comment: The correct behavior would be more in line with that exposed by a browser, however the current behavior of `.error` (which seems to be aware of the special toString) would be satisfactory.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Henke A bug report is not a question.

Comment: OK. Thanks for clarifying.
I was actually looking for some Meta guidance on whether printouts in a caught
error / exception should be done with `console.log()` or with `console.error()`?
Your post was the closest I could find.
My own opinion is that `console.error()` is preferable.
And as I understand
[this comment of yours](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/370046#comment603192_370046),
you agree with me?

Comment: @Henke it would depend on your use case.  I believe It's probable that `console.error()` would suit the majority of use cases.