# How can I search for posts that contain Stack Snippets?

Tags: support, search, stack-snippets

I want to search for posts which have live Stack Snippets.

[Example post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55412706/convert-an-object-to-object-array/55412727#55412727): the snippet markdown content is:

```
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

<!-- language: lang-js -->

    const obj = { "name1" : "value1", "name2" : "value2", "name3" : "value3", "name4" : "value4" };
    const arrOfObjs = Object.entries(obj).map(([key, val]) => ({ [key]: val }));
    console.log(arrOfObjs);

<!-- end snippet -- >
```

`begin snippet` looks like a promising phrase that should occur in every post with a snippet, but unfortunately, only the few [badly formatted results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22begin+snippet%22) are returned. ["end snippet"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22end+snippet%22) doesn't work either. I don't see anything about this on the [searching](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) page.

I suppose one tedious possibility would be to write some code to use the [API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) to retrieve the `body_markdown` of every recent post, and keep going until enough posts with snippet markdown have been found, but that's ugly.

Is there a better way, hopefully by using the built-in search box? Lacking that, could this be done with a SEDE query?

Comment: (background: looking for lots of snippets to test the script I'm writing against, which will help solve [this problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381594/is-stack-snippet-that-useful-when-it-cannot-help-discovering-errors-when-writing))

Comment: `hascode:1` exists, but isn’t specifically for Stack Snippets.

Comment: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1021327 next time please remind me that text search on SEDE is no fun.