# Code snippet console render BigInt incorrectly

Tags: bug, stack-snippets

The `console.log` in code snippet currently does not support BigInt. To reproduce this problem, you may simply run this code snippet. The console shows `null` instead of `42`. And it should show something meaningful: Maybe `42n` or at least `42`.

```js
console.log(42n);
console.log([42n]);
```

Comment: Relevant: [Stack Snippets Console can't output ES6 data types](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/375887)

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, this isn't an isolated occurrence, since the [Stack Snippets console can't output ES6 data types](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/375887), and BigInt is even newer than ES6 ([from ES2020](https://nitayneeman.com/posts/introducing-bigint-primitive-in-ecmascript-2020/)). Stack Snippets (and its console) haven't been updated in a good while.

As far as I can tell, the (virtual) console used by Stack Snippets hasn't been meaningfully updated with new language features since [its initial release](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/279420), based on the then-current version of [@canon's](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/621962/canon) [`stack-snippet-console` script on GitHub](https://github.com/gh-canon/stack-snippet-console).

In [the answer from that ES6 snippets post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/375985) from Oct. 2018, @canon revealed an enhanced version of that same script that supports ES6 types, but it was never adopted into Snippets on the site, and it [hasn't been updated since](https://github.com/gh-canon/stack-snippet-console/commits/master), which means it doesn't support any more recent features from 2019 onward, like BigInt.

As a workaround, your browser's console should display these values correctly (as long as [it itself supports them](https://caniuse.com/bigint)), but for now, Snippets are stuck in pre-ES6 land until they get some much-needed TLC (maybe as [a plugin for the new editor](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/425146)?).

> [image: OP's snippet with browser console pulled up to show that BigInt console output appears correctly]