# Stack Snippets console doesn't display JS BigInts

Tags: bug, stack-snippets

`1n` is a BigInt literal in JavaScript. BigInts currently display incorrectly/ don't display at all in the Stack Snippet console; `console.log(1n)` logs nothing and `console.log([1n])` logs `[null]` instead of correctly displaying the BigInt values `1n` and `[1n]`.

Compared to an actual browser console, which logs the BigInt value correctly both as-is and in an array:

> [image: Screenshot of two lines of browser console output showing "1n" on line 1 and "[1n]" on line 2]

Example Snippet:

```js
console.log(1n) // logs nothing
console.log([1n]) // logs [null]
```

Comment: I just tried the first example from [BigInt - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) and looks like Stack Snippets doesn't correctly print BigInt in any format?

Comment: Related: [Stack Snippets Console can't output ES6 data types](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/375887) | JS [Bigints are an ES2020 feature](https://nitayneeman.com/posts/introducing-bigint-primitive-in-ecmascript-2020/), and Snippets don't even properly support all ES6 types yet, unfortunately. Snippets could really use some love.

Comment: Looks like there's actually an exact dupe for this one from a few years ago (...which I apparently answered lol): [Code snippet console render BigInt incorrectly](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/403669)